# ValidationExpression in RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've e-mail validation regex like this

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TxtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
 ControlToValidate="TxtEmail" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="#007528" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([.]\w+)*">      </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

It doesn't accept following mail adres : `test-1-@hotmail.com`

How can I edit regex?

Comment: You shouldn't use regular expressions for email validation purposes, although there is one, that accepts the valid emails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: [Email Regular Expressions](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=email&c=-1&m=5&ps=20)

Eg.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server"
 ControlToValidate="TxtEmail" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="#007528" 
 ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-]+[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\_\\-]*@([a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|travel|museum)$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Try this:
**Email Regular Expression:**

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-]*@([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|travel|museum)$
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought that in ASP.Net Visual Studio gives you some selections for common regex validations like telephone number and email. For email I use the regex below, it works for your example:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your regular expression is that not accept -+.' if is not accompanied of a alphanumerical character, plus you accept other things like `asdf@asd.cl#safd` as a valid string until the # character, you can use the expression `^\w+([-+.']+\w*)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([.]\w+)+$` I add the begin of line and the end of line at the beginning and the end, and change `([-+.']+\w+)` for `([-+.']+\w*)` to accept zero or more alphanumeric characters.  I hope this help.